# fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource

Tags: php, fopen, fread

This is driving me a little mad, thought perhaps it could be a server config issue, but I have tried it on a different host and get the same issue.

I have narrowed it down and created a test script to rule everything out

```
<?php
$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r') || die("Couln't open file");
if ( $fh == true ) {
        echo "file handle valid<br>";
}
else {
        echo "file handle invalid<br>";
}
$theData = fread($fh, filesize($myFile)) || die("Couldn't read file");
echo $theData;
fclose($fh)|| die("Couldn't close file");
?>
```

When test.txt is missing  I correctly get the die couldn't open file
When test.txt is there I get

**Warning: fread(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in**

I have set test.txt to 777 to be sure

I also wrote this just to double check, which works fine

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('test.txt');
echo $data;
?>
```

Hopefully someone can shed some light on this for me.

Answer (score 2):

You'e been bitten by [operator precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) in PHP. `||` has a higher precedence than `=`, so you're actually assigning the result of a logical OR to `$fh`. Switching to

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r') or die("Couln't open file");
                          ^^--- lower precedence logical or
```

will fix thigns up.

With `or`, the return value of `fopen()` is assigned to `$fh`, then the `or die()` is evaluated - if fopen() returns a file handle, the or will fail and code proceedes. If fopen fails, a boolean false is returned and the or die kicks in.

With `||`, the value of fopen is logically ORred with the die call, and the result of that or (false) will be assigned to $fh.

Answer (score 1):

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'r') || die("Couln't open file");
```

You are assigning a boolean expression to `$fh`, losing the actual file handle in the process. Try changing the above line to

```
($fh = fopen($myFile, 'r')) || die("Couln't open file");
```